# What should be used to substitute BasicNameValuePair in building URL?

Tags: android

I am using below code to build URL for networking. I have been using [`BasicNameValuePair`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) and `URLEncodedUtils` to build URL but now since android 5.0 both have been deprecated. So what shall i use to create URl?

```
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("APPID", "0000000000000000"));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", String.valueOf(latitude)));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", String.valueOf(longitude)));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "accurate"));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("units", "metric"));

                // Create a new URL
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" + "?" + URLEncodedUtils.format(pairs, "utf-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Samvid ...use volley library

```
public static void postNewComment(Context context,final UserAccount userAccount,final String comment,final int blogId,final int postId){
mPostCommentResponse.requestStarted();
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://api.someservice.com/post/comment", new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        mPostCommentResponse.requestCompleted();
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        mPostCommentResponse.requestEndedWithError(error);
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("user",userAccount.getUsername());
        params.put("pass",userAccount.getPassword());
        params.put("comment", Uri.encode(comment));
        params.put("comment_post_ID",String.valueOf(postId));
        params.put("blogId",String.valueOf(blogId));

        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return params;
    }
};
queue.add(sr);
}

public interface PostCommentResponseListener {
public void requestStarted();
public void requestCompleted();
public void requestEndedWithError(VolleyError error);
}
```

this is the basic example ... you can use acc. to your need

Answer (score 0):

In my code I replaced it with a very simple and small self-written class - an inner class in my case:
https://github.com/murraycu/android-galaxyzoo/commit/38964e79fa4eb36ced4a14e3d2565b6e78763080

```
public static class NameValuePair {
        private final String name;
        private final String value;

        public NameValuePair(final String name, final String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }

        String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

The deprecation comment for BasicNameValuePair is indeed unhelpful.

However, that wasn't for building a URL.